# Fluid column arrangement

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show some checkboxes in a table style, but I need the number of columns to be decided based on the screen's width. If I let them to rearrange on their own, I end with something like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                     |
|   [] label1  [] label2  [] label3  [] label 4       |
| [] label5          [] label6   [] label7            |
|     [] label8  []label9  [] label10  []label11      |
|                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

and I need something like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                     |
|   [] label1  [] label2  [] label3  [] label4        |
|   [] label5  [] label6  [] label7  [] label8        |
|   []label9   [] label10 []label11                   |
|                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

I don't care if the columns are the same width or not, but I need the full thing to fill the 100% of the container.

Comment: Look into media queries to set a fixed structure based on window size.

Answer (score 2):

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:300px;
    padding:10px;
}
#container div {
    width:70px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Bu4M/1/)

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I can't set explicitly the width of each element, because I don't know how long each label will be.

Comment: @CésarGarcíaTapia you didn't mentioned this in your question.